# Spring in Kotlin, JWT Token encoded with base64url

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to create a JWT token with `NimbusJwtEncoder`, and I'm getting a token correctly. but each time i verify it on `jwt.io` it says that the signature is invalid, because it is not encoded correctly on base64url.

like this last test token

```
"eyJraWQiOiJabVZrWWpBMk56TXRaR1V6WmkwMFpEVXlMVGt5TUdNdE5qUmlabUpoWmpVeU5HWTQiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzZWxmIiwic3ViIjoiU2FoZXIgQWxTb3VzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc5OTQ1MTIxLCJpYXQiOjE2Nzk5Mzk3MjEsInNjb3BlIjoiUk9MRV9VU0VSIn0.tLTsk03Rg7ZjY3yjyM_lGveeT0KRCPJBSBlpcOzXA3n4pGA5TjHSD3GdVL3tGhH1kyhLt2Xqk2Mwa88w6fWeBvrBa3V8M8GVcZKusXS52XxDlBSag6ouQKsqQBk3HRDfORHw_U5SwV2Yuu_gFlghDjv2A9wNv8lTQSKSEwS4vsm7UOZQX9ERMdWTbKaW4-CTAiHazGsmRViiWpiYKkp4p0EZez_p0vSaQ_nFhQ_uuU9W_7HjkJgC4kD9mMhrdyhOpXllwkZkxP5VIkuRKKa4_uooUSP_taTloSZiYITz-CTgFsqekmHZhVj72bFDINBzO3pzbavjagwT1vJcw4reEA"
```

i changed several ways to generate the key including the Base64 encoders but same result.

am i missing something out or what?

```
Security Configuration

 @Bean
    fun jwkSource(): JWKSource<SecurityContext> {
        val jwkSet = JWKSet(rsaKey())
        return JWKSource { jwkSelector: JWKSelector, _: SecurityContext? ->
            jwkSelector.select(
                jwkSet
            )
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtEncoder(jwkSource: JWKSource<SecurityContext>): JwtEncoder {
        return NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource)
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtDecoder(): JwtDecoder {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder
            .withPublicKey(rsaKey().toRSAPublicKey())
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun rsaKey(): RSAKey {
        val keyPair = keyPair()
        return RSAKey.Builder(keyPair.public as RSAPublicKey)
            .privateKey(keyPair.private as RSAPrivateKey)
            .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun keyPair(): KeyPair {
        return try {
            val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048)
            keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw IllegalStateException(
                "Unable to generate an RSA Key Pair", e
            )
        }
    }
```

```
class JwtTokenService(private val jwtEncoder: JwtEncoder) {
    fun generateToken(authentication: Authentication): String {
        val scope = authentication
            .authorities
            .joinToString(" ") {obj: GrantedAuthority ->
                obj.authority
            }

        val claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
            .issuer("self")
            .issuedAt(Instant.now())
            .expiresAt(Instant.now().plus(90, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
            .subject(authentication.name)
            .claim("scope", scope)
            .build()

        return jwtEncoder
            .encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims))
            .tokenValue
    }
}
```

I keep getting these 2 warnings... by the way when you move the mouse over the token yellow area the warnings disappear...
[image: warning message]

[image: whole view]

Comment: *each time i verify it on jwt.io it says that the signature is invalid, because it is not encoded correctly on base64url.* - No, it doesn't say anything about the encoding of the signature. It just says "invalid signature", which is just because you (and I) did not provide the public key which is necessary to verify the signature. A signature can only be validated with a key, without a key, it's not possible. And the token that you show in your post is correctly Base64Url encoded, with `_` and `-`  substituting `/` and `+`.

Comment: there are 2 warning over the key area that speaks about the base64 encoding... I don't know how to provide the public key to the website then...

Comment: I just updated the question to include the warnings I'm talking about.

Comment: Strange. I don't get any warning with your token. Please show me a full screenshot of jwt.io that includes your token.

Comment: done... please check it!

Comment: The problem is that you pasted the string including the "". If you remove these extra characters it will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I want to keep this one over here...
this is the correct way to create a JWT with Spring in kotlin using `NimbusJwtEncoder`.

I hope that someone will get use of it.

regards.